# Find a specific word in a cell and copy the rows next to it to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to copy rows A-E whenever the word FLAG is found in row H and I want to skip all rows where Flag is not found. Below is  example of the table I am working with and what I would want my result table to look like.

This is the code I have, however it is not copying the rows A-E that have Flag it is just copying the first three rows to the new sheet.

```
Sub foo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Duration")
    Dim wsResult As Worksheet: Set wsResult = Sheets("Report")

    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To LastRow 
        For x = 8 To 8 
            If ws.Cells(i, x) = "FLAG" Then 
                NextFreeRow = wsResult.Cells(wsResult.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                ws.Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Copy  
                wsResult.Range("A" & NextFreeRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 
                ws.Cells(i, x - 4).Copy 
                wsResult.Cells(NextFreeRow, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                ws.Cells(i,x-3).Copy
                wsResult.Cells(NextFreeRow, 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            End If
        Next x
    Next i
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Has code indentation become uncool?

Comment: by "row" do you mean columns? in excel, rows are numbers and columns are letters

Answer (score 1):

If you want to alter the copying from A to C to A to E, then this will do that:

```
Sub foo()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Duration")
Dim wsResult As Worksheet: Set wsResult = Sheets("Report")

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 3 To LastRow
        If ws.Cells(i, 8) = "FLAG" Then
            NextFreeRow = wsResult.Cells(wsResult.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ws.Range("A" & i & ":E" & i).Copy Destination:=wsResult.Range("A" & NextFreeRow)
            'the code below will have to be amended if you changed your table's layout and you also want some other cells copied as well as A to E
            'ws.Cells(i, 4).Copy
            'wsResult.Cells(NextFreeRow, 6).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            'ws.Cells(i, 5).Copy
            'wsResult.Cells(NextFreeRow, 7).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I think the Cells(i, 4).Copy and Cells(i, 5).Copy lines were wrong to begin with.

Comment: @Jeeped, probably, but as this is a follow up question to a previously answered one, I thought I would continue the OPs vernacular and simply show him how to copy range A to E for that specific row, I'm sure the other two Cells(i, 4) & 5 can easily be amended if he lets us know which columns contain the desired data...

Comment: @Jeeped, of course you are right, I've amended my answer to reflect your comment.. :)

Comment: This code is still only copying over the first 2 columns

Comment: @Numb3ers it should be copying the Cells from A:E on the row which had "FLAG" on column 8 (H). As the line `ws.Range("A" & i & ":E" & i).Copy` suggests.

Answer (score 0):

if you have to copy worksheet "Duration" columns A-E rows whose corresponding column H cell value is "Flag" and paste them to worksheet "Report" columns A-E starting form last not empty cell in column A, then go like this (explanations in comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub foo()
    Dim wsResult As Worksheet: Set wsResult = Sheets("Report")

    With Worksheets("Duration")
        With .Range("A2:H" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) 'reference its columns A:H cells from row 2 (header) down to last not empty one in column "A"
            .AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:="FLAG" ' filter referenced cells on 8thd column "FLAG" content
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(8)) > 1 Then .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=wsResult.Cells(wsResult.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) ' if any filtered cell other than the header then copy their first five columns and paste to 'wsResult' sheet starting from its column A last not empty cell
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Numb3ers, any feedback?